# All GNOME parts are showing in English even if the Language is “Chinese (China)”

Tags: gnome, language-support

All GNOME parts are showing in English even if the Language is “Chinese (China)”, except GDM.
I tried to switch languages in `gnome-control-center` for many times, but it does not take any effects. (like Chinese, other languages do not work too)
EDIT: not about input method. Ubuntu ver: 22.04.1 LTS Linux ver: 5.19.0-38-generic
Output of `locale`:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MERSUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere (can't tell exactly where/how) you have explicitly set:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

Doing so on a desktop is wrong, and you effectively disable any GUI controls for changing language. So you should drop those settings and instead rely on the GUI for handling locale settings.

Comment: Thanks. I solved this question by myself. I just added `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8` and `LANGUAGE=zh_CN.UTF-8` to Xsession .desktop file and it works.